# How to assign the same value to multiple variables in a class in django models

Tags: python, django

In the below class orders, I want to assign the same value of weight to the amount

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    consignment_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key='consignment_id', auto_created=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    from_place = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.FloatField(weight)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Pending')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the save function in the model

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    consignment_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key='consignment_id', auto_created=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    from_place = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Pending')

    def save(self):
        self.amount = self.weight
        super().save(self)
```